# AWS CDK: How to integrate API gateway with ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService in private subnets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

### Problem

I need create a public API in AWS which will be integrated with multiple services: including multiple fargate services, EC2 services, and Lambda, etc. You can think it as twitter or facebook public API. Something like this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/architecting-multiple-microservices-behind-a-single-domain-with-amazon-api-gateway/

Now I'm working on integrating one of its endpoint to an "ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService".

I only see HTTPIntegration and LambdaIntegration there, not "AlbIntegration".

[image]

Therefore, I picked `HTTPIntegration` which requires `VPCLLink`.

Then I find that the "targets" attribute in `ApiGateway.VpcLink` only support `INetworkLoadBalancer` type. But my fargate service is created with `EcsPatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService`.

So the error I see at line `targets: [PandaServiceLoadBalancer]` is :

```
Type 'IApplicationLoadBalancer' is not assignable to type 'INetworkLoadBalancer'.
  Types of property 'addListener' are incompatible.
```

[image]

What change should I make here to make it work?

Should I change my fargate service to `EcsPatterns.NetworkLoadBalancedFargateService` to make it easier?

### Details

I have a fargate service defined as this:

```js
    this.fargateService =
      new EcsPatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService(
        this,
        `${props.stageName}-${this.serviceName}-ID`,
        {
          cluster: PandaServiceFargetCluster, // Required
          //loadBalancerName: "PandaServiceLoadBalancer",
          serviceName: "PandaService",
          desiredCount: 1, // Increase it for better scalability.
          taskDefinition: this.createFargateTask(props),
          publicLoadBalancer: true, // Default is false
          healthCheckGracePeriod: CDK.Duration.minutes(1),
          circuitBreaker: {
            rollback: true,
          },
        }
      );
```

Now in my public API gateway, I want to integrate it with the fargate service.

```js
import * as CDK from "aws-cdk-lib";

import * as CertificateManager from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-certificatemanager";
import * as Route53 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-route53";
import * as ApiGateway from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway";

import * as ELBv2 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-elasticloadbalancingv2";
import { Construct } from "constructs";
import { StageInfo } from "../config/stage-config";
import * as EC2 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2";


...
...
...
    this.vpcLink = new ApiGateway.VpcLink(this, `${this.constructIdPrefix}VpcLinkCreation`, {
       vpcLinkName: "PandaServiceVpcLink"
       targets: [PandaServiceLoadBalancer]
    });

    this.pandaApi = new ApiGateway.RestApi(
      this,
      `${this.constructIdPrefix}-pandaApi`,
      {
        description: "The centralized API for panda.com",
        domainName: {
          domainName: props.stageInfo.domainName,
          certificate: domainCertificate,
          //mappingKey: props.pipelineStageInfo.stageName
        },
        defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
          allowOrigins: ApiGateway.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
          allowMethods: [...ApiGateway.Cors.DEFAULT_HEADERS],
        },
      }
    );


    const productsResource = this.pandaApi.root.addResource("products");
    productsResource.addMethod(
      "GET",
      new ApiGateway.HttpIntegration(
        `${props.stageInfo.PandaServiceLoadBalancerDns}/products`,
        {
          httpMethod: "GET",
          options: {
            connectionType: ApiGateway.ConnectionType.VPC_LINK,
            vpcLink: this.vpcLink,
          },
        }
      )
    );
```

Comment: I switched to `EcsPatterns.NetworkLoadBalancedFargateService` and get it work, as I don't see a solution to integrate with ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.